# JS para somar checkbox on-line

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox, soma

Não tenho grande conhecimento de js, então preciso de uma ajuda. Tenho uma pagina que gera um formulario com um mapa de cotação, em colunas (cada fornecedor em uma coluna), e preciso que ao usuario selecionar os checkbox ele faça a soma on-line pois cada fornecedor tem um valor mínimo para poder autorizar o faturamento.

A questão é que o script usa o name=dias[] em todos os checkbox, e preciso de um nome diferente para cada fornecedor, isso eu consigo fazer pelo php com uso de variáveis, mas como eu faço para que o js consiga criar multiplos códigos pegando o nome da minha variavel do checkbox ?

Parte do código php que gera o resultado e os checkbox:

```
        #Monta listagem de valores referente ao produtos

        //selecionando os valores    
        $sqlValores = "SELECT v.total, id_precos, v.preco
                       FROM tbl_cot_precos AS v
                       WHERE id_produto = '" .$produtos['produtosCod'][$i]. "'
                       AND v.id_pedido =$id_pedido";            
        $resValores = mysql_query($sqlValores);




        while ($listaValores = mysql_fetch_array($resValores))
        {
            //exibe valores

            echo '<td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_unit" value="' .number_format($listaValores[2], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_total" value="' .number_format($listaValores[0], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="produto_id_'.$listaValores[1].'" value="'.$listaValores[1].'"></td>
                  <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="'.$id_pedido.'"></td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias[]" value="'.$listaValores[0].'"></td>';    

        }


        $i++;
        #Fim monta listagem de preços referente ao produtos

    echo '</tr>';
```

js que faz a soma on-line dos checkbox que são clicados:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".dias").change(function() {
              var total = $('input[class="dias"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
              return tot + Number(el.value);
           }, 0);
           $('#resultado').val(total);
         });
       });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Você precisa criar muitos código e pretende armazenar onde? Primeiro em array ou direto no banco de dados?

Comment: Onde entra a identificação de cada fornecedor nisso?

Comment: Os dados dos fornecedores e os preços de cada um já ficam no BD, nessa rotina eu apenas demonstro para o usuário, a questão é que como ele pode comprar produtos de vários fornecedores, preciso que ele ao escolher faça a soma e confronte com a informação de valor mínimo de compra. Então precisa que o JS conseguisse pegar o ID do checkbox de cada fornecedor, o nome do ID do checkbox eu consigo por exemplio atribuir o codigo do fornecedor, mas como o JS vai saber esse nome ?

Comment: Aqui no código eu posso acrescentar o codigo do fornecedor no BD <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_$id_fornecedor[]" value="'.$listaValores[0].'"></td>';

Comment: Voce quer o nome do check para atribuir o código?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo básico para você dar uma analisada

Olha só:

Criei um vetor chamado: `codigo` que vai armazenar somente os códigos

Ao clicar, ele faz a soma dos totais e exibe em local

Daí você pode pegar o exemplo e vê se te ajuda

Segue o código abaixo:

```js
var codigo = []

$('.dias').on('change', function(){
      
      var values = 0.00;
      let id = $(this).closest('tr').find( '.id' ).text()
      var total = $('input[class="dias"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
              return tot + Number(el.value);
           }, 0);
      $('span').text( 'Soma total: '+total ) 
      let _id = codigo.indexOf( id )
      if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
         if( ( _id == -1 ) ) {
            codigo.push( id )
         }
      }else{
        codigo.splice( _id, 1 )  
      }
      
      console.log( 'codigos', codigo )
      
      
    
      
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span></span>

<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
         <td class="valor">200</td> 
         <td class="id">1</td> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias[]" value="200"></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td class="valor">300</td>  
         <td class="id">2</td> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias[]" value="300"></td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
         <td class="valor">600</td>  
         <td class="id">3</td> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias[]" value="600"></td>  
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um objeto com as somas para cada fornecedor diferente. Digamos que você coloque no `name` de cada checkbox um fornecedor diferente:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f1[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f2[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f1[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f2[]" value="1">
```

Repare que em cada checkbox acima existe uma diferenciação, onde `f1` e `f2` seriam os id's de cada fornecedor vindo do PHP:

```
name="dias_$id_fornecedor[]"
```

Com isso você consegue montar um objeto em JavaScript com a soma de cada checkbox checado separando os id's dos fornecedores. Digamos que foi checado todos os checkbox acima, irá resultar num objeto assim:

```
fornecedores = {
   f1: 9,
   f2: 3
}
```

Com esse objeto em mãos você poderá verificar os valores de cada entrada do objeto pelo id de cada fornecedor (`f1`, `f2` conforme exemplo).

Seu código ficará assim:

```
$(function(){
   $(".dias").change(function(){

      var fornecedores = {};
      $('input.dias:checked').each(function(){
         var id_fornecedor = this.name.match(/dias_(.+?)\[\]/)[1];
         if(fornecedores[id_fornecedor]){
            fornecedores[id_fornecedor] += +this.value;
         }else{
            fornecedores[id_fornecedor] = +this.value;
         }
      });
      
      var total = $('.dias:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
         return tot + Number(el.value);
      }, 0);
      $('#resultado').val(total);
   });
});
```

**Teste:**

```js
$(function(){
   $(".dias").change(function(){

      var fornecedores = {};
      $('input.dias:checked').each(function(){
         var id_fornecedor = this.name.match(/dias_(.+?)\[\]/)[1];
         if(fornecedores[id_fornecedor]){
            fornecedores[id_fornecedor] += +this.value;
         }else{
            fornecedores[id_fornecedor] = +this.value;
         }
      });
      console.log(fornecedores); // remova esta linha
      var total = $('.dias:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
         return tot + Number(el.value);
      }, 0);
      $('#resultado').val(total);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_unit" value="' .number_format($listaValores[2], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_total" value="' .number_format($listaValores[0], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="produto_id_'.$listaValores[1].'" value="'.$listaValores[1].'"></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="'.$id_pedido.'"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f1[]" value="3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_unit" value="' .number_format($listaValores[2], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_total" value="' .number_format($listaValores[0], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="produto_id_'.$listaValores[1].'" value="'.$listaValores[1].'"></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="'.$id_pedido.'"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f2[]" value="2"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_unit" value="' .number_format($listaValores[2], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_total" value="' .number_format($listaValores[0], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="produto_id_'.$listaValores[1].'" value="'.$listaValores[1].'"></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="'.$id_pedido.'"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f1[]" value="5"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_unit" value="' .number_format($listaValores[2], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td align="right"><input type="text" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10px" size="12" name="valor_total" value="' .number_format($listaValores[0], 2, ',', '.'). '" readonly></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="produto_id_'.$listaValores[1].'" value="'.$listaValores[1].'"></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="'.$id_pedido.'"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_f2[]" value="9"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input id="resultado">
```

## Observações:

- `jQuery(function() {` e `$(document).ready(function() {` é a mesma coisa. Não repita.
- Esse seletor `$('input[class="dias"]:checked')` pode ser simplificado assim `$('input.dias:checked')`.

Comment: Obrigado, mas vamos lá....me perdoe se deixei algum detalhe passar.Mas, mas ainda o elemento resultado está somando todos os checkbox, independente do nome.

Comment: Ele gerou os nomes diferene, veja: td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_9[]" value="300"></td></tr>                  td><input type="checkbox" class="dias" name="dias_6[]" value="300"></td></tr> Aonde 6 e 9 são od ids de cada fornecedor

Comment: veja em : http://simpleprice.com.br/financeiro/view_mapa_cotacao_soma.php?id=000001